# Will Stack Exchange API include API for "Documentation"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

My use case was related to versions of the technologies. Stack Overflow documentation can be a single place in future to get a list of all available versions of a particular technology. Also, it would be better to add "deprecated" or "extended support" etc. to the versions table.

Comment: Let's wait until we know whether it's going to make it out of Beta first :)

Comment: I am not sure that such obsolete questions should be closed (and may be deleted). If yes, it should require at least some community consent. The question was useful as the Doc SE existed.